# Ruby on rails: Remote Upload A File Using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've successfully uploaded a file using PUT and html, but is there a way to upload a file in a ajax remote_form_for ?

I've tried this to no success:

```
<% remote_form_for @song,:html => { :multipart => true }, :url => { :action => 'upload' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Rails 3, try the Remotipart gem. It makes AJAX style file uploads relatively painless.

http://rubygems.org/gems/remotipart

http://github.com/leppert/remotipart

Answer (score 2):

The standard remote_form_for doesn’t understand multipart form submission so you can't actually do this without some leg-work as indicated by *yoda* above.

The other way to achieve this is by using an iframe.